# graphite puppet error while installation

Tags: ruby, puppet, graphite, puppetlabs-apache

Getting the below error while installing graphite server using puppet

The pupet module installed for graphite

```
puppet module install dwerder-graphite
```

This is the content of graphite.pp

```
cat graphite.pp
```

The output

```
class {'graphite':
}
```

This the Command

```
puppet apply graphite.pp
```

The error what i received:

```
warning: Scope(Class[Graphite::Params]): Could not look up qualified variable 'graphite::gr_web_group'; class graphite has not been evaluated at /etc/puppet/modules/graphite/manifests/params.pp:97
warning: Scope(Class[Graphite::Params]): Could not look up qualified variable 'graphite::gr_web_group'; class graphite has not been evaluated at /etc/puppet/modules/graphite/manifests/params.pp:97
warning: Scope(Class[Graphite::Params]): Could not look up qualified variable 'graphite::gr_web_user'; class graphite has not been evaluated at /etc/puppet/modules/graphite/manifests/params.pp:103
warning: Scope(Class[Graphite::Params]): Could not look up qualified variable 'graphite::gr_web_user'; class graphite has not been evaluated at /etc/puppet/modules/graphite/manifests/params.pp:103
Failed to parse template graphite/opt/graphite/conf/carbon.conf.erb:
  Filepath: /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/scope.rb
  Line: 459
  Detail: undefined method `[]' for #<Puppet::Parser::Scope:0x7f82caef1e98>
 at /etc/puppet/modules/graphite/manifests/config.pp:171 on node test
```

I'm running on RHEL

```
 cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.4 (Santiago)
```

Comment: You might want to bring this up as an issue with the module's developer.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you put file `graphite.pp`? Here is way to test the modules recommend by Puppetlabs.

If you puppet modules is /etc/puppet/modules, then create tests folder under it, and create `graphite.pp`, then add content in it:

```
include graphite
```

When you manually apply the change, run this command:

```
cd /etc/puppet/modules/tests
puppet apply --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules graphite.pp
```

Comment: [root@rhel-lnx ~]# ls -l /root/graphite.pp 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 Jan  9 03:45 /root/graphite.pp

Comment: So that's the problem, and I gave the fix.